# Select all distinct pairs from a list of object using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the list of objects. For the simplicity, let's say objects are strings.

```
    var strList = new List<object>() { "one", "two", "three" };
```

I would like to generate all distinct pairs. If I have a pair `("one" & "two")` I should not have also the pair `("two" & "one")`.

This is the code I use:

```
    var pairs = strList.SelectMany(x => strList, (x, y) =>
    Tuple.Create(x, y)).Where(x => x.Item1 != x.Item2);

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Item1 + " & " + pair.Item2);
```

**Output:**

`one & two
one & three
two & one
two & three
three & one
three & two`

**Desired output:**

`one & two
one & three
two & three`

Is there any simple way to accomplish that using LINQ?

**Update:**
Please before mark this question as duplicate consider that I am looking for a solution using LINQ which will apply to a list of any objects, regardless of `CompareTo` is defined for it or not.

**Solution:**

If someone will come across to this question finally, I found the simple solution:

```
var pairs = strList.SelectMany(x => strList, (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y)).
    Where(x => strList.IndexOf(x.Item1) < strList.IndexOf(x.Item2));
```

Comment: I do not see how this question is duplicate of the referred one. The question is not about "all combinations" it's about all distinct combinations. Part one of the answers to the referred (K-combinations) looks related to this question. However, there is a significant difference, which could not be applied here. It uses the `CompareTo` which cannot be used here for any objects.

Comment: That's probably because you don't read all answers.

Comment: @GertArnold I look at all the answers but could not see the one which fits my problem. Could you please indicate which one you mean?